# How to use StartRTPDump() function in WebRTC correctly?

Tags: c++, webrtc

I am sending an audio stream from my browser (Chrome) to the "peerconnection_client" sample application (trunk\talk\examples\peerconnection) and trying to dump it into a file using [StartRTPDump](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/webrtc-internals/voertp_rtcp#TOC-StartRTPDump):

```
int StartRTPDump(int channel, const char fileNameUTF8[1024], RTPDirections direction = kRtpIncoming);
```

Here is my test code:

```
void Conductor::OnPeerConnected(int id, const std::string& name) {
  LOG(INFO) << __FUNCTION__;
  // Refresh the list if we're showing it.
  if (main_wnd_->current_ui() == MainWindow::LIST_PEERS)
      main_wnd_->SwitchToPeerList(client_->peers());

  // My test code
  {
      voe_ = webrtc::VoiceEngine::Create();
      webrtc::VoEBase* voeBase = webrtc::VoEBase::GetInterface(voe_);
      rtp_rtcp_ = webrtc::VoERTP_RTCP::GetInterface(voe_);
      voeBase->Init();
      channelId_ = voeBase->CreateChannel();
      bool isActive = rtp_rtcp_->RTPDumpIsActive(channelId_); // "isActive" is false
      int ret = rtp_rtcp_->StartRTPDump(channelId_, "AudioStreamFromRemotePeer.rtp"); // "ret" is 0
      isActive = rtp_rtcp_->RTPDumpIsActive(channelId_); // "isActive" is true
  }
}

void Conductor::OnPeerDisconnected(int id) {
  LOG(INFO) << __FUNCTION__;
  if (id == peer_id_) {
    LOG(INFO) << "Our peer disconnected";
    main_wnd_->QueueUIThreadCallback(PEER_CONNECTION_CLOSED, NULL);
  } else {
    // Refresh the list if we're showing it.
    if (main_wnd_->current_ui() == MainWindow::LIST_PEERS)
      main_wnd_->SwitchToPeerList(client_->peers());
  }

  // My test code
  {
      bool isActive = rtp_rtcp_->RTPDumpIsActive(channelId_); // "isActive" is true
      int ret = rtp_rtcp_->StopRTPDump(channelId_); // "ret" is 0
      isActive = rtp_rtcp_->RTPDumpIsActive(channelId_); // "isActive" is false
      rtp_rtcp_->Release();
      webrtc::VoiceEngine::Delete(voe_);
  }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint inside the following function **after calling OnPeerConnected() but before OnPeerDisconnected()**:

```
int32_t Channel::ReceivedRTPPacket(const int8_t* data, int32_t length, const PacketTime& packet_time)
{
    WEBRTC_TRACE(kTraceStream, kTraceVoice, VoEId(_instanceId,_channelId), "Channel::ReceivedRTPPacket()"); // "_channelId" here matches to "channelId_" above
    ....
}
```

I can see incoming data.

But the generated .rtp file after calling OnPeerDisconnected() looks like:

[image]

Why am I not getting any data in my .rtp file?